# pyspark streaming gives ImportError: No module named _winreg when reading from checkpoints

Tags: pyspark, spark-streaming

I am using pyspark streaming and have enabled the checkpoints.
If the job fails and I restart with the saved checkpoints, there is an exception 
ImportError: No module named _winreg.

If I delete the checkpoints and start the job it has no issues.

I am running this on Ubuntu.
Pyspark application is run as part of jupyter notebook. The failure occurs when the notebook is restarted. At that point the program should read the checkpoints and start from last consumed offsets but fails.
Following command is used to start the notebook with pyspark:
IPYTHON_OPTS="notebook --ip=0.0.0.0" /opt/spark/bin/pyspark

This is how I create the streaming context:

```
ssc = StreamingContext.getActiveOrCreate("/mnt/secure/checkpoints/" + app_name, lambda : create_streaming_context(app_name, batch_interval, max_rate_per_partition))
```

below is part of exception trace:

> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/lib/six.py", line 105, in _resolve
>       return _import_module(self.mod)
>     File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/lib/six.py", line 76, in _import_module
>       **import**(name)
>   ImportError: No module named _winreg
>
> at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryOrIOException(Utils.scala:1207)
>       at org.apache.spark.streaming.api.python.TransformFunction.writeObject(PythonDStream.scala:100)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>       at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1028)
>       at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1496)
>       at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
>       at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)

Comment: Some details could be useful (OS, environment, how it is executed).

Comment: I have edited the question to add some more details.

Comment: Here the answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42252770/pyspark-streaming-restore-from-checkpoint